# Some curiosity about dice coefficient calculation

Tags: model-evaluation

In semantic segmentation task evaluation with the following properties :

- batch size of the test set : 4
- shape of a target mask/predicted mask : (1, 512, 512)
- number of batches in the test set : **30**
- used dice score calculation formula : Sum of [(2 x (target_batch * pred_batch).sum + 1e-8) / (target_batch.sum + pred_batch.sum + 1e-8)]

In order to evaluate a model's performance with the Dice Coefficient, which one is a **proper way** to do it?

1. evaluate summed DL(according to the formula given above), and divide it with 30 (# of batches in the test set) to give an *averaged* final Dice Score evaluation of the model.
2. Set batch size of the test set as 1 (single sample), and evaluate summed DL(according to the formula given above). Then, divide it with the sample size of the test set to give a final Dice Score evaluation of the model.

Also, I would like to know why is that a proper way to do it.

Comment: If your *dice* is [Lee Raymond Dice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lee_R._Dice) then it might be worth a capital letter to clarify you are not talking about random numbers from a cube.